# The map wasn't shown, Fabulous for Xamarin.Forms (using Maps, full Elmish)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, f#, elmish

I modify the example of Fabulous for Xamarin.Forms (Using Maps, full Elmish) : "https://fsprojects.github.io/Fabulous/Fabulous.XamarinForms/views-maps.html". However, the outcome is not same as I expected. The map wasn't shown, please advise how to fix the problem. Thank you.

```
// Copyright 2018-2019 Fabulous contributors. See LICENSE.md for license.
namespace SqueakyApp

open System.Diagnostics
open Fabulous
open Fabulous.XamarinForms
open Fabulous.XamarinForms.LiveUpdate
open Fabulous.XamarinForms.MapsExtension
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Maps

module App =
    // Declaration
    type Model =
        { Count : int
          Step : int
          Pressed : bool }

    type Msg =
        | Increment
        | Decrement
        | UserLocation

    // Functions

    // Lifecycle
    let initModel =
        { Count = 0
          Step = 0
          Pressed = false }

    let init() = initModel, Cmd.none

    let update msg model =
        match msg with
        | Increment -> { model with Count = model.Count + model.Step }, Cmd.none
        | Decrement -> { model with Count = model.Count - model.Step }, Cmd.none
        | Reset -> init()

    let view (model : Model) dispatch =

        let paris = Position(48.8566, 2.3522)
        let london = Position(51.5074, -0.1278)
        let calais = Position(50.9513, 1.8587)
        let timbuktu = Position(16.7666, -3.0026)

        let map =
            View.Map
                (hasZoomEnabled = true, hasScrollEnabled = true,
                 pins = [ View.Pin(paris, label = "Paris", pinType = PinType.Place)
                          View.Pin(london, label = "London", pinType = PinType.Place) ],
                 requestedRegion = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(calais, Distance.FromKilometers(300.0)))
        // View
        View.ContentPage(content = map)

    // Note, this declaration is needed if you enable LiveUpdate
    let program = Program.mkProgram init update view

type App() as app =
    inherit Application()

    let runner =
        App.program
        |> Program.withConsoleTrace
        |> XamarinFormsProgram.run app
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Comment: How did you change the sample code?

Comment: Modify the 'View" section in visual studio for OS X. The project(solution) can be compiled  successfully, but the map cannot be shown.

Comment: Is the only change the new line adding `let timbuktu = ...`, or is there anything else? And what exactly do you mean by "map cannot be shown"? Do you see a white screen or something along those lines?

Comment: @TomasPetricek, I have enclose a screen shot for reference. I expected a map and some pins which are shown on screen.

Comment: Good job on figuring this out! Could you edit your question and post the answer part as an answer? (It may feel a bit odd, but it's a standard way of posting solutions to your own questions on SO...)

Comment: @TomasPetricek, Fabulous & F# are awesome alternative of iOS development. I did react-native iOS development, react-native is not good for complex mobile development(sounds a bit biased, MVU is more natural than redux, RxJS, Mobx on application architecture). It seems there is missing for someone to write the book on it(e.g Fabulous in Action, Fabulous in Depth etc), new developer like me spend a lot of time to discover how certain things work.

Answer (score 1):

Learning an example from Timothé Larivière (https://github.com/TimLariviere/FabulousContacts).

It is necessary to initialize the FormsMaps in the file "AppDelegate.fs" under the sub-directory .iOS. There is a source file for reference.

```
// Copyright 2018 Fabulous contributors. See LICENSE.md for license.
namespace SqueakyApp.iOS

open System
open UIKit
open Foundation
open Xamarin
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS

[<Register ("AppDelegate")>]
type AppDelegate () =
    inherit FormsApplicationDelegate ()

    override this.FinishedLaunching (app, options) =
        Forms.Init()
        FormsMaps.Init() //*** initialization the FormsMaps is required 
        let appcore = new SqueakyApp.App()
        this.LoadApplication (appcore)
        base.FinishedLaunching(app, options)

module Main =
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate")
        0
```

[image]